# unable to search through Facebook Graph API for colleges/Institute names

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two app pages : one is in Test mode and the other is open for public

Previously I was using following URL to fetch the list

"graph.facebook.com/search?limit=10&type=adcollege&q=somestring&access_token=myapptoken"

but its retuerns

Error : "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",

So checked and modified it to

"graph.facebook.com/search?limit=10&type=adeducationschool&q=somestring&access_token=myapptoken"

bt now it returns,

Error: "(#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management and an application that is whitelisted to access the Ads API",

I am going through the documentation of FB version upgrade, bt can not find any information other than PMD.

Any help appreciated.
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of the Facebook Platform. Have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/790175311021543/

The FB docs contradict themselves:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/targeting/ vs.
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data

Comment: thanks @Tobi, Yes, even the docs not specifying the correct parameter 'type' to use.